# Flutter mocktail write unit test for cloud_firestore get function

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, google-cloud-firestore

I have problem with write test for cloud_firestore get data collection.

it's my function code to check nickname saved in document in firestore:

```
 @override
  Future<Either<String, Unit>> checkNickname({required String nickname}) async {
    try {
      final document =
          await firestore.collection(FirebaseCollection.users.name).get();

      for (var element in document.docs) {
        var user = element.data();
        if (user['nickname'] == nickname) {
          throw BusyNickname();
        }
      }
      return const Right(unit);
    } on BusyNickname catch (_) {
      return const Left(nicknameBusy);
    }
  }
```

to test i used `fake_cloud_firestore` package

my test code:

```
  test('checkNickname should return Left if nickname is busy',
              () async {
            final firestore = FakeFirebaseFirestore();
            final collection =
                firestore.collection(FirebaseCollection.users.name);
            final doc = collection.doc('test');
            await doc.set({'nickname': 'nickname'});

            when(() => cloudFirestore
                .collection(FirebaseCollection.users.name)
                .get()).thenAnswer((_) => collection.get());

            var result = await repositoryImpl.checkNickname(
              nickname: 'nickname',
            );

            // Assert the result
            expect(result, const Left(nicknameBusy));
          });
```

But test not pass and i get this error message in terminal

```
UnimplementedError: collection
package:test_api                                                            Fake.noSuchMethod
test/features/auth/data/repositories/auth_repository_impl_test.dart 16:7    MockFirebaseFirestore.collection
test/features/auth/data/repositories/auth_repository_impl_test.dart 360:18  main.<fn>.<fn>.<fn>.<fn>
package:mocktail/src/mocktail.dart 211:8                                    when.<fn>
test/features/auth/data/repositories/auth_repository_impl_test.dart 359:17  main.<fn>.<fn>.<fn>
```

Anyone know how write this unit test?

Edit 1:
RepositoryImpl constructor

```
 AuthRepositoryImpl({
    required this.firebaseAuth,
    required this.firestore,
  });

  final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
  final FirebaseFirestore firestore;
```

In Test:

```
class MockFirebaseFirestore extends Fake implements FirebaseFirestore {}

void main() {
 late MockFirebaseFirestore cloudFirestore;

setUpAll(() {
    ...
    cloudFirestore = MockFirebaseFirestore();
    repositoryImpl = AuthRepositoryImpl(
      ...
      firestore: cloudFirestore,
    );
  });

  ... rest of code ...
}
```

Comment: Please show the rest of your code. Where is `firestore` defined before it's used in the `checkNickname` method and where is `cloudFirestore` defined in your test code.

Comment: In the meantime, checkout this blog post I wrote on testing Firebase operations in Flutter unit tests: https://blog.victoreronmosele.com/mocking-firestore-flutter.

Comment: @VictorEronmosele i edit the post

Comment: Checkout my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77497018/11039164).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The Problem:

### No implementation for collection for `MockFirebaseFirestore:`

You're getting the `UnimplementedError: collection` error because you don't have an implementation for `collection` for your `MockFirebaseFirestore`, a [Fake](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/test_api.fake/Fake-class.html).

`MockFirebaseFirestore` being a `Fake` means you need to override its methods before you use them, or else you get an `UnimplementedError`.

## The Solution:

### Use only `FakeFirebaseFirestore:`

You're currently using `MockFirebaseFirestore` in the `AuthRepositoryImpl` class which forwards the `get()` calls to `FakeFirebaseFirestore` which holds the Firestore data.

```dart
 when(() => cloudFirestore
                .collection(FirebaseCollection.users.name)
                .get()).thenAnswer((_) => collection.get());
```

`MockFirebaseFirestore` is redundant in this case since you need to forward the calls and also you need to override all the methods you need.

`FakeFirebaseFirestore` is already a `Fake` and it has [implemented all those methods](https://github.com/atn832/fake_cloud_firestore/blob/f0493d85f82e91c7301e64630cfa8cf25f731).

### Code:

```dart
void main() {
  test('checkNickname should return Left if nickname is busy', () async {
    final firestore = FakeFirebaseFirestore();

    final collection = firestore.collection(FirebaseCollection.users.name);
    final doc = collection.doc('test');
    await doc.set({'nickname': 'nickname'});

    AuthRepositoryImpl repositoryImpl = AuthRepositoryImpl(
      firestore: firestore,
    );

    final result = await repositoryImpl.checkNickname(
      nickname: 'nickname',
    );

    // // Assert the result
    expect(result, const Left(nicknameBusy));
  });
}
```

The code above does the following:

- Removes `MockFirebaseFirestore` and its references.
- Defines the `AuthRepositoryImpl` in the test function so it can receive the `FakeFirebaseFirestore` instance relevant to the test.
- Passes the `FakeFirebaseFirestore` instance as an argument to `AuthRepositoryImpl`.